# Deleting rows if a cell isn't white

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro who does:

- copies three data ranges from "Import" sheet (1) to sheets 2-9 (ranges are specific for each one).
- then, if the cell in G is empty OR (non exclusive) if the cell on F isn't white, deleting the line
- finally, making a special copy-paste "values" of cells H and I from all non-empty lines, because they contains formula (respectively for H and I):

`=SI(C4<>"";CONCATENER(C4;"M");"")`

`=SI(C4<>"";CONCATENER(C4;"N");"")`

File is organized as follows:

Sheet 1:
Raw datas, organized by columns, from A to BI

Sheets 2 to 9:
Columns from A to I

Sheet 10:
A merged cell, nothing to do here

For this, I've made with some code from Internet and my meager knowledge, but that not works, especially color-filtering.

Thanks in advance

```
Dim J As Integer

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(2).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("J:M").Copy Sheets(2).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(3).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(3).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("R:U").Copy Sheets(3).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(4).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(4).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("V:Y").Copy Sheets(4).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(5).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(5).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("Z:AC").Copy Sheets(5).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(6).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(6).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("AL:AO").Copy Sheets(6).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(7).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(7).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("AT:AW").Copy Sheets(7).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(8).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(8).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("AX:BA").Copy Sheets(8).Range("D:G")

Sheets("Import").Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(9).Range("A:B")
Sheets("Import").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(9).Range("C:C")
Sheets("Import").Range("BF:BI").Copy Sheets(9).Range("D:G")

For J = 2 To 9
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Sheets(J).Select

Dim I As Long
Dim redRng As Range
Set redRng = Range("F2", Range("F600").End(xlUp))

Set ws = Sheets(J)
With Sheets(J)
lRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Colonne G = delta

For I = lRow To 2 Step -1
    If InStr(Sheets(J).Range("G" & I), "") = 0 Or Sheets(J).Cells(I, "F").Interior.ColorIndex <> 2 Then
    .Range("G" & I).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
   Next I
Exit For

'Dim Nodel As Boolean
'lastrow2 = Sheets(J).Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'For H = lastrow2 To 2 Step -1
'Nodel = False
    'If .Cells(H, "F").Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then Nodel = True
    'If Not Nodel Then .Rows(H).EntireRow.Delete
    'Next H

End With
Next J
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you identify when a cell in column G is non-exclusive?

Comment: The word "non-exclusive" refers to the OR in my sentence. I mean it's "G is empty, F isn't white or both"

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  Can you edit your question above with a clearer explanation of what you want to happen to columns H and I.

Comment: That 2 formulas are built to write something in the cell where they respectively are, if something is written in C column. I just want to copy and special paste "values" them, if C column is filled with something, after the loop(s?) to delete if F / G is …. I hope I'm clear

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code below and it works for me.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()

Dim i%
Dim j&, lastRow&, lastRow2&, lastRow3&
Dim sRange$
Dim Nodel As Boolean
Dim WS As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet

'using WS instead of Sheets("Import") makes the code more readable
Set WS = Sheets("Import")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(2).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(2).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("J:M").Copy Sheets(2).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(3).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(3).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("R:U").Copy Sheets(3).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(4).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(4).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("V:Y").Copy Sheets(4).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(5).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(5).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("Z:AC").Copy Sheets(5).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(6).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(6).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("AL:AO").Copy Sheets(6).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(7).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(7).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("AT:AW").Copy Sheets(7).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(8).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(8).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("AX:BA").Copy Sheets(8).Range("D:G")

WS.Range("B:C").Copy Sheets(9).Range("A:B")
WS.Range("G:G").Copy Sheets(9).Range("C:C")
WS.Range("BF:BI").Copy Sheets(9).Range("D:G")

For i = 2 To 9
    'assigning to variable helps when interrogating WS2 variable through watch
    Set WS2 = Sheets(i)
    With WS2
        lastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Colonne G = delta
        
        For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1
            '-4142 is another colorindex for white
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(j, 7)) Or .Cells(j, 6).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
                .Range("G" & j).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
        
'        lastRow2 = .Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
'
'        For j = lastRow2 To 2 Step -1
'            If .Cells(j, 6).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
'                .Rows("F" & j).EntireRow.Delete
'            End If
'        Next j

        lastRow3 = .Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        sRange = "C2:C" & lastRow3

        ' any cell in column C containing a value will have the formula removed and the cell simply set to a value
        ' any cell in column C containing a blank will have the formula removed and the cell simply set to a blank
        .Range(sRange).Copy
        .Range(sRange).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        
        'this turns off the flowing dotted line we get when we do a copy
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Got an error 1004 at line "Range("G" & j).EntireRow.Delete": delete method of class "range" failed

Comment: Dear Felix. If we're using the same code and it works for me but not for you, then it is a data issue. When you get an error in VBA, a small panel appears with three buttons: End, Debug, and Help. If you click on Debug, you'll be able to interrogate the live code. If you hover over j, you'll be able to see it's value. That's the row with some issue that's causing the error.

Comment: Hello Cyrus, I just tried your macro and it works. However, it works a bit too much because it deleted EVERY line except headers, including lines with G row filled with something and F row in white.

Comment: Hello Felix. Very generously put. I'm being sincere. What happens if you change -4142 to 2 in your version of the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, even after tried replacing value, it still works as described

Comment: It works for me but not for you, then it must be a data issue. You could put a breakpoint at the -4142 line of code and determine why it wants to delete a couple of rows?